# Xcode 6.1 won't let me create a new project

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm running Xcode 6.1 on OS X Yosemite and I'm unable to create a new project, as you can see below it just says 'loading'.

I've removed the product and org name for the purpose of this image. I have tried uninstalling but that didn't work. I am new to Xcode and coding in general so I would appreciate it if any solution could be given in lay terms.

[image: Choose options for your new project]

Comment: I get the same behavior *until* I enter a product name. Spinning wheel remains, but the "Next" button gets enabled. Does the "Next" button remain disabled in your case even after entering a project name?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have something entered in Organization Name and Organization Identifier. Right now it can be any placeholder. I think it matters later on when you're submitting projects to the App Store.